# How can I share a folder that needs credentials to view the contents on different workgroups/domains

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, authentication, shared-folders

I would like to share a folder on my personal laptop so I can access it through the network in my work environment but would like some form of authentication so that not just anyone can view the contents. The work network uses a domain which the laptop is not a member of so currently to access it I have shared to "Everyone". Is there a way that I can share the folder that has a popup asking for a user and password before access is granted? I don't want to have to join the network on my laptop as I use it at home on a workgroup. Laptop is an Accer Aspire 5755G 64Bit Windows 7 ultimate.

Is there anything similar to the protection you can put on Office documents that can be applied to folders?

Comment: Seems a simpler solution would be to mark the folder as a [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) folder or use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) for remote access

Comment: It might be simpler but simple is not always better. The folder is 80GB so don't want to share that through drop box and remote access is a lot slower than viewing the shared folder in a network environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just remove the Everyone permissions from the share and only add a local user from the laptop. When you attempt to connect it should prompt for a username and password, just type in your login on the laptop and you should be able to connect.

P.S. A little trick of windows, if you have a user with the same username and password as a local user as your domain username and password windows attempts to use those credentials first before showing the password prompt, if you keep your laptop's password in sync with your domain password it should "just work" and connect you to the share without ever prompting you for a password.

Comment: Hi @Scott when I removed the user everyone it now says "you do not have permission to access \\pc\folder. contact your network admin to request access"

Comment: You can manually set the credentials for the share by using the [NET USE](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command on the domain computer you are trying to connect to the laptop with. `NET USE \\pc\folder password /user:pc\WillNZ` should do the trick.